# Match_parent not working in ImageView in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new here and trying to learning android programming but i got a problem and unable to fix this, kindly help me on this. I am using Android Studio 2.3 and problem is when i try to use "match_parent" value in

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

it auto turn into below:-

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />
```

below is the my complete code, kindly help me on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.rj.happybirthday.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Happy Birthday Rj!"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:text="From, Rj!"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/party"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: dont use contraints layout to start learning, use just lreative and linear layout, once u are master at them then just learning constraints. THis is new autogenerated layout remove it.

Comment: @sector11 Since it's auto included in every new project I'd consider it fit for starting with Android development. True, **it's intended to work better with visual layout editor** not direct XML coding.

Comment: thanks for reply, now that i need to do? how can i convert this into Relative Layout as ConstraintLayout is by default in AS 2.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` child views cannot specify `match_parent` as their desired dimensions. Use `match_constraint` (0dp) with left/right or top/bottom constraints set to `"parent"`.

> #### Widgets dimension constraints
>
> The dimension of the widgets can be specified by setting the  `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes in 3 different ways:
>
> - Using a specific dimension (either a literal value such as `123dp` or a `Dimension` reference)
> - Using `WRAP_CONTENT`, which will ask the widget to compute its own size
> - Using `0dp`, which is the equivalent of "`MATCH_CONSTRAINT`"
>
> [image: Dimension Contraints]
>
> ***Fig. 7 - Dimension Constraints***
>
> The first two works in a similar fashion as other layouts. The last one will resize the widget in such a way as matching the constraints that are set (see Fig. 7, (a) is wrap_content, (b) is 0dp). If margins are set, they will be taken in account in the computation (Fig. 7, (c) with 0dp).
>
> **Important**: `MATCH_PARENT` is not supported for widgets contained in a `ConstraintLayout`, though similar behavior can be defined by using `MATCH_CONSTRAINT` with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to `"parent"`.

Source : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html